# How to call WebSockets directly via Java? (Was "WebSockets with Application.cfm?")

Tags: java, websocket, coldfusion

I'd initially asked this:

Is it possible to use WebSockets with Application.cfm instead of Application.cfc?  If so, how would one implement it?

But now it's more about enabling WebSocket channels in Application.cfm via direct java.  Anybody know how to do such a thing?  Check out the comments below for what I've found (or more accurately, not found) so far.

Comment: Why not just convert your application.cfm to an application.cfc?  This is the better way to go for many reasons.

Comment: Yes, I can do that -- and will.  But meanwhile, is this even possible or does the utilization of the application.cfm framework prevent the usage of WebSockets?

Comment: I don't think Application.cfm or Application.cfc have anything to do with using web sockets. However, using ColdFusion 10 or later does (web sockets was introduced with version 10). The fact that you are still using Application.cfm makes me believe that you are running an older version of ColdFusion that does not support the built in web socket functionality. To be clear, you don't need ColdFusion to use web sockets - [examples](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/#toc-serverside)

Comment: According to all the examples I saw, I believe Application.cfc is required, as the following has to go into it: this.name = "WebSocketDemo"; this.wschannels = [{name="stocks"},{name="chat"}]; there is no way of putting this info into application.cfm as far as I can see?  This is an old system with very legacy code, but we are on ColdFusion 11.

Comment: FYI, I tried adding "<cfset application.wschannels = [{name="stocks"},{name="chat"}]>" and "<cfset application.this.wschannels = [{name="stocks"},{name="chat"}]>", but no dice.

Comment: Now I have to tell you, I'm just kind of curious -- what exactly does this.wschannel do to the underlying java, and is it possible to call this any other way?  this.name = 'whatever' is basically <cfapplication name="whatever'>; that's what the cfdump of the application variable tells me.  But there's no scope variable that I can see that shows wschannel, so it must get translated into some other java call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there is no way to work with ColdFusion's WebSockets via application.cfm (if I'm wrong, please somebody correct me -- I'm talking about the CF-built-in WebSockets!).  But it turns out there's a very easy way of moving from application.cfm to application.cfc.  It's here:

https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2019/10/on-converting-from-application-cfm-to-cfc/

The money link is the broken-looking page from Hostek:

https://forum.hostek.com/showthread.php?724-Converting-to-Application-cfc

So it can literally be that simple -- just including your application.cfm in the application.cfc.  This is definitely a bit of a hack, but it works.  Big thanks to Charlie Arehart for posting this.